# Erro no mapeamento dinâmico: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, reflexão, dapper, automapper

Eu tenho um dicionário de dados mais ou menos assim:

```
public class Colunas 
{
   public string ColunaOrigem {get; set;}
   public string ColunaDestino {get; set;}
   public DbType Tipo {get; set;}
}

public class Tabela
{
   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public IList<Coluna> Colunas {get; set;}
}


var dicionarioDados = new Tabela();
```

Uso a classe **System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder** para gerar um tipo em tempo de execução.

Uso o Dapper para pegar os dados no banco de dados e gerar uma variável com o tipo da tabela, por exemplo:

```
var resultado = connection.Query(typeof(classeGerada), "select * from Tabela");
```

Agora eu gostaria de fazer um mapeamento da classeGerada para classeGerada2, a diferença das duas é que uma só tem duas colunas e a outra tem todas as colunas.

Estou tentando fazer isso utilizando AutoMapper (não achei como fazer em outra biblioteca, aceito sugestão).
Estou usando o seguinte mapeamento:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(f => f.CreateMap(targetClass, sourceClass)
                      .ForMember("Sequencial", m => m.MapFrom("TabelaId")));
```

Quando executo

```
var resultadoMapeado = Mapper.Map(resultado , sourceClass);
```

tenho o seguinte erro:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> Type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] ->
>   System.Type

***sourceClass é o tipo gerado em tempo de execução a partir do dicionario de dados.**

Alguém sabe dizer o que está errado? Ou qual seria a forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Acredito que o erro é mediante ao tipo gerado em tempo de execução que é um `Object` e não consegue passar para o tipo é isso...!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic como resolvo isso entao? A classe precisa ser dinamica, e preciso gerar ela a partir do dicionario de dados. Mas preciso mapear o mesmo resultado para dois objetos diferentes que so tem duas propriedades em comun.

Comment: @Acredito https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping tem um exemplo de algo que possa te ajudar, porque na sua pergunta não tem como gerar um exemplo minimo, você poderia colocar o exemplo na integra?

Comment: Você conseguiu fazer funcionar sem tentar utilizar o `TypeBuilder`? Ou seja, criando uma classe *na mão mesmo*, criando a classe de destino na mão também, e tentando utilizar o Auto Mapper? Tente fazer funcionar assim primeiro.....depois tente utilizar de forma dinâmica. Aparentemente a classe `targetClass` tem alguma property do tipo `IEnumerable` que não existe na `sourceClass`. Como não sabemos como são ambos tipos (ambas classes), não temos como ajudar muito. Só se alguém já tentou fazer isso e passou pelo mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa antes configurar dos tipos que deseja mapear, tente utilizar o código abaixo:

```
    private static IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
        cfg.CreateMap<TipoTargetClass, TipoSourceClass>();
    }).CreateMapper();
```

Obs.: Substitua os textos TipoTargetClass e TipoSourceClass para o tipo correto dos seus objetos.